# Explicit std::unique_lock constructor from mutex

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, implicit-conversion, explicit-constructor

I see that the constructor overload that takes a mutex is marked `explicit`. I don't see the reason to specify it so. I think there is no harm to allow implicit conversion from mutex to a corresponding `std::unique_lock`. This can actually be convenient. For example, given `void func_a(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock)` and `std::mutex mut`, we could directly invoke `func_a` on `mut` like `func_a(mut)`. What may be the potential harm with respect to the call `func_a(mut)`? I don't think there is any effect that may surprise the user. So, the question is: what is the rationale behind marking the constructor `explicit`?

Comment: Why doesn't a raw pointer implicitly convert to `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: One obvious rationale for an `explicit` conversion is to ensure that it will always be explicit. This is especially important for operations that in some sense pass ownership.

Comment: This question may be definitely answerable if someone takes the effort to dig up the original proposal, so I'm not voting to close.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf [Nope](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html). It's just taken for granted.

Comment: @T.C. Because `std::unique_ptr` performs `delete` on the raw pointer. If I pass raw pointer to a function, I would not expect it to do such things. Allowing implicit conversion would surprise me in this case.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I agree. But I think `std::unique_lock` does not take ownership of the mutex in one way or another.

Comment: @Lingxi Locking a mutex is *owning* it. (`unique_lock` has a member called `owns_lock`, hint, hint.) Writing correct synchronization code is hard enough without having mutexes implicitly locked all over the place, potentially causing UB or deadlocks in the process.